# How to use OpenAz ServiceFactory method?

Tags: java, xacml, xacml3

I am using OpenAz as PEP client for my project but I am confused about it's serviceFactory. Can you please share a code snippet how to create a service in openAz.

I believe it's done through-> org.openliberty.openaz.pdp.provider.AzServiceFactory;

but I couldn't see any service creation implementation inside the source file. Please help me out if anyone has any idea about OpenAz.

Comment: Hi Nik, use the OpenAZ mailing list to post such questions where they will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David suggests, the best way to get ongoing help is on the OpenAz
maillist, which you can browse or join @:
http://lists.openliberty.org/mailman/listinfo/openaz

Briefly, there are a few places in the code base that use
AzServiceFactory. Probably the best one at present is in
the TestUtils module method setupAzService, which is used
in most of the testing on the site:
http://sourceforge.net/p/openaz/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/openaz/test/src/test/TestUtils.java

In that module, lines 171->203 are a few examples of
usage of AzServiceFactory.registerProvider()

Thanks,
  Rich